# How do I properly use HTML decode?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, tinymce

I have some text stored in a database:

```
&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Hi this is Roht &amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;Singh&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
```

When I retrieve it and HTML decode it into a label control it gives me this text:

```
<p>Hi this is Roht <strong>Singh</strong></p>
```

My code:

```
 label1.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());
```

How can I render the text as HTML like so?

> Hi this is Roht **Singh**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your data is HTML encoded twice. Try decoding it twice:

```
label1.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(
                    Server.HtmlDecode(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString()
              );
```

When you take your original data:

```
&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Hi this is Roht &amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;Singh&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
```

And HTML decode it, you get the following:

```
&lt;p&gt;Hi this is Roht &lt;strong&gt;Singh&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

When you HTML decode that result, you get:

```
<p>Hi this is Roht <strong>Singh</strong></p>
```

Which should then be rendered as:

> Hi this is Roht **Singh**

Comment: i used literal as well, still the same

Comment: See my edit. It looks like the database data was double-encoded.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it i have htmldecode once more the text and it is working.
Ans: Server.HtmlDecode(Server.HtmlDecode(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString()));